# Where can I find road attribute and network for New York City?

Tags: data, united-states, transportation

Is there any possible to find the attribute of each road (such as road capacity, speed, longitude and latitude.) in New York City?

Answer (score 3):

You can try free and open OpenStreetMap data. For NYC-data in various formats see this link: http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/new-york.html. However, keep in mind that OSM data is gathered by thousands of volunteers around the world and there is no guarantee of completeness and thematic accuracy but the data is very good for larger and populous cities/areas like NYC.

Speed limits (maxspeed=) and road capacity (lanes=) are attributs and lon-lat values can be computed in your geographic information system of choice, e.g. Quantum GIS (http://www.qgis.org).